# google api geolocation not found

Tags: android, geolocation, geocode

i'm creating an android app that use GMAPS to catch my position and find hotspots using wifiscanner.

i was reading that if you use geolocation i can get with Json Format info of Wifi in my area.

I have setted a key in my account but if i use this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

it give me in the web page not found.
But if i use the geocoding it works.

and i can have this result

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

how can i do to work with geolocation?
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Are you using GET? It should be a POST request.

Geolocation requests are sent using **POST** to the following URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY